# How do I change the category my Area 51 proposal is in?

Tags: support, area-51

I noticed that the proposals on Area 51 have now been placed in categories. Who decided which category each proposal is in?

Is there a way for me to change the category my proposal is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only staff members have the ability to change proposal categories. As of now, the recommended way to go about it is to get a staff member's attention by suggesting that the proposal be re-categorized in the [Area 51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/).